# Devops2019 JobAgent Down after URL Change

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, build-agent, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent

We are using Devops 2019 (App and data tiers are on two different servers),As part of our domain migration we have changed our Devops URL
from: https:\domain.wireless.com
to: https:\domain.wire.com

But post URL change, we have noticed all the build agents stopped working (self hosted agents ) and when admin console is launched and tried to send test mail I see below:

---

```
Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: 
An unexpected error occurred on a send. (type WebException)Exception Stack Trace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Admin.Console.Models.DlgSendTestMailViewModel.SendEmail()
```

Inner Exception Details:

```
Exception Message: Unable to read data from the transport connection:
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (type IOException)
Exception Stack Trace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
```

Need some assistance on how to resolve such issues

Answer (score 1):

Probably not your ideal approach, but you could just remove and register the agents using the new URL.  You'd have to reset any custom capabilities afterwards.

For windows, the URL is stored in a hidden file at the agent root folder.  I don't think it works just modifying it in that agent configuration, but you could try changing one and stop/start the agent if it is running as a service.  If it is running auto-login (maybe for UI testing), I've never had any success except for removing/reconfiguring.